# C++ Passing 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, arguments, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I am trying to create a minesweeper game that loads the board from a flat file (no, it's not random). As per the assignment instructions, I am to pass a 2d array to a load function which will then parse the file which was passed as a command-line arguement.

Anyway, my problem is passing the 2D array. What is the proper way to go about doing it? Below is the code that I have thus-far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Tile
{
    bool mine, visible;
    int danger;
};

bool loadBoard( Tile **board, string filename );

const int gridSize = 6;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Tile board[ gridSize ][ gridSize ];

    loadBoard( board, argv[ 1 ] );

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool loadBoard( Tile **board, string filename ) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using C++, why not use

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>
```

in preference to a C-style array?

Since you seem to need to use C-style arrays, you could use the approach arpanchaudhury suggests or you could pass `Tile*` and do something like

```
static void loadBoard(Tile *board, int rows, int cols, string filename) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            Tile* tile = &board[(row*gridSize)+col];
            // populate Tile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's for a school assignment and we have a specific set of instructions. :)

Comment: Ok, that's a good reason.  I've updated my answer with an option in keeping with your constraints.

Comment: I find this sort of attitude very annoying but I've done some breathing exercises and calmed down before replying. This code/approach is garbage. You're a newbie in this area, by learning from some expert suggestions here you can rapidly progress. Dismissing suggestions as not being part of your assignment will not help you. Your teacher is probably an idiot. Suppose different people want to play with different size boards. Are you going to write a separate loader for every possibility? One loader should be able to load a board of any row/col combination as its size will be in the data.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Not sure whether you were trying to respond to me or the O/P but its a reasonable point that `loadBoard` could be improved. I've updated my code to show this.

Comment: It was @user1960364 not you!

Comment: @TheMathemagician I concur (and fully expect my answer to be downvoted  heavily, but i'm not exactly in a caring mood right now =P

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to to pass the 2d-array please specify number of columns in the array.

`bool loadBoard( Tile board[][size], string filename ) {}`

though it is preferable to use vectors instead of simple arrays since you need not specify a pre-defined size

Comment: It may be better to pass bool loadBoard(Tile& board[][size], string filename)?

Comment: no it will produce same result. as for arrays reference is passed by default

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using C++...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Tile
{
    bool mine, visible;
    int danger;
};

// load a square board of declared-size.
template<size_t N>
void loadboard( Tile (&board)[N][N], const std::string& filename)
{
    // load board here.
    cout << "Loading from file: " << filename << endl;
    for (size_t i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        cout << "board[" << i << "]: [ ";
        for (size_t j=0;j<N;++j)
        {
            // load element board[i][j] here
            cout << j << ' ';
        }
        cout << ']' << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Tile board[6][6];
    loadboard(board, "yourfilename.bin");   // OK dims are the same

    Tile smaller[3][3];
    loadboard(smaller, "anotherfile.bin");  // OK. dims are the same

    // Tile oddboard[5][6];
    // loadboard(oddboard, "anotherfile.bin"); // Error: dims are not the same.

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Loading from file: yourfilename.bin
board[0]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]
board[1]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]
board[2]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]
board[3]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]
board[4]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]
board[5]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]

Loading from file: anotherfile.bin
board[0]: [ 0 1 2 ]
board[1]: [ 0 1 2 ]
board[2]: [ 0 1 2 ]
```

Of course, there are probably "specific instructions" to not use the templates feature of the language either. Then again, I bet those instructions don't include having SO users solve your problem either, so I don't take much stock in those being followed rigorously anytime soon.